# ViewPager View Visibility issues

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view

I have a ViewPager with 3 fragments. Each of them contain the same views and the views animate when the fragments are visible to the user. I am overriding setUserVisibleHint to start the animations. When I swipe to the fragments the views are still there for a second, disappear and then start the animation.
I want to completely remove the views when they are not visible and when swiping to the fragment they become visible and the animation starts.
Basically I have tried to hide them inside the setUserVisibleHint when the parameter is false. This does nothing. The views are still visible even when the fragment is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You should use ViewPager with Tablayout so that this kind of problem not occured in this case...

Refer below link,

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new TabFragment();    // Which Fragment should be dislpayed by the viewpager for the given position
                                    // In my case we are showing up only one fragment in all the three tabs so we are
                                    // not worrying about the position and just returning the TabFragment
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;           // As there are only 3 Tabs
    }

}
```

http://www.android4devs.com/2015/12/tab-layout-material-design-support.html

I wish it may help you...